# how to edit and save abc.testsettings(xml) file in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have file with below content. I want to delete all the element under DeploymentItem and create new.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="Settings" id="6f67be45-4967-40c3-a89f7665cc7f654e2" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
  <Deployment>
<DeploymentItem filename="TestCaseXml\LTestCases.xml" />
<DeploymentItem filename="..\..\Framework\Common\Xmls\TestSuite.xml" />
<DeploymentItem filename="TestCaseXml\bTestCases.xml" />
<DeploymentItem filename="TestCaseXml\PTestCases.xml" />
<DeploymentItem filename="TestCaseXml\1TestCases.xml" />
</Deployment>
</TestSettings>
```

when I am using below code it is giving me output given below

```
XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
            doc2.Load(testBinaryFile);
foreach (XmlNode node in doc2.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
                {
                if (node.Name == "Deployment")
                {
                    node.RemoveAll();

                    foreach(string element in Folders)
                    {
                        if(!element.Contains("Scripts"))
                        {
                            string[] Files7 = Directory.GetFiles(element);
                            foreach(string File2 in Files7)
                            {
                                string addName = File2.Substring(File2.LastIndexOf(@"TestBinaries\")).Replace("TestBinaries\\", "");
                                XmlElement elem = doc2.CreateElement("DeploymentItem");
                                elem.InnerText = "filename='" +  addName + "'";
                                node.AppendChild(elem);
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string addName = element.Substring(element.LastIndexOf("TestBinaries\\")).Replace("TestBinaries\\","") + "\\";
                            XmlElement elem = doc2.CreateElement("DeploymentItem");
                            elem.InnerText = @"filename='" + addName + "'";
                            node.AppendChild(elem);
                        }
                    }

                    doc2.Save(testBinaryFile);
                }   



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="Settings" id="6f67be45-4967-40c3-a89f7665cc7f654e2" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
  <Deployment>
<DeploymentItem xmlns="">filename='Scripts\'</DeploymentItem>
<DeploymentItem xmlns="">filename='TestCaseXml\bTestCases.xml'</DeploymentItem>
<DeploymentItem xmlns="">filename='Xmls\TestSuite.xml'</DeploymentItem>
  </Deployment>
</TestSettings>
```

I want output as given below. please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="Settings" id="6f67be45-4967-40c3-a89f7665cc7f654e2" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
  <Deployment>
<DeploymentItem filename='Scripts\' />
<DeploymentItem filename='TestCaseXml\bTestCases.xml' />
<DeploymentItem filename='Xmls\TestSuite.xml' />
  </Deployment>
</TestSettings>
```

Comment: Because `filename` in your first and last samples is an attribute of `DeploymentItem` but you are using `InnerText` and that creates child element.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to attribute. after correcting the code I am getting below output.

      <Deployment>
    <DeploymentItem filename="'Scripts'" xmlns="" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="'TestCaseXml\bTestCases.xml'" xmlns="" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="'Xmls\TestSuite.xml'" xmlns="" />
  </Deployment>

why  xmlns=""  is added and how to remove it.

Comment: @User that's because your XML has *default namespace*, but your code creates new element in *empty namespace*. Check my answer for how to fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding `xmlns=""` being added to the new elements, that's because your XML has default namespace. Note that in XML, descendant elements inherit ancestor default namespace implicitly, unless otherwise specified.

That said, in the expected output you posted, `DeploymentItem` are in default namespace `"http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010"`.

You can use [`CreateElement()` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c22k3d47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which accept prefix, localName, namespaceURI parameters to create element in namespace. To be specific, try to replace this line :

```
XmlElement elem = doc2.CreateElement("DeploymentItem");
```

with this one :

```
XmlElement elem = doc2.CreateElement(
                            string.Empty, 
                            "DeploymentItem", 
                            "http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010"
                      );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chuck Savage and har07 for solving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication33
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = 
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                "<TestSettings name=\"Settings\" id=\"6f67be45-4967-40c3-a89f7665cc7f654e2\" xmlns=\"http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010\">\n" +
                  "<Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>\n" +
                  "<Deployment>\n" +
                "<DeploymentItem filename=\"TestCaseXml\\LTestCases.xml\" />\n" +
                "<DeploymentItem filename=\"..\\..\\Framework\\Common\\Xmls\\TestSuite.xml\" />\n" +
                "<DeploymentItem filename=\"TestCaseXml\\bTestCases.xml\" />\n" +
                "<DeploymentItem filename=\"TestCaseXml\\PTestCases.xml\" />\n" +
                "<DeploymentItem filename=\"TestCaseXml\\1TestCases.xml\" />\n" +
                "</Deployment>\n" +
                "</TestSettings>\n";

            string defaultItems =
                "<DeploymentItem xmlns=\"\">filename='Scripts\'</DeploymentItem>\n" +
                "<DeploymentItem xmlns=\"\">filename='TestCaseXml\\TestCases.xml'</DeploymentItem>\n" +
                "<DeploymentItem xmlns=\"\">filename='Xmls\\TestSuite.xml'</DeploymentItem>\n";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(input);
            XmlNode deployment = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Deployment")[0];
            deployment.RemoveAll();
            deployment.InnerXml = defaultItems;


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this is not correct  Chuck Savage from above comment pointed me correct. but I am getting xmlns=""  in xml and wanted to remove it.